# What is the name of this eclipse cycle (if there is one)?

Tags: observational-astronomy, solar-eclipse

Today I navigated to Wikipedia's "**Eclipse Cycle**" page and found that they had updated their table of eclipse cycles with many more named cycles. However, one particular cycle that I had recently wanted to find was still NOT among them. The cycle in question is the outcome of the eclipse equation "**11i-13s**" (in terms of "inex + saros" calculations). This eclipse cycle calculates to 84.0035 Tropical years (or 84 years + 1.28 days). I was surprised that it was not yet named because it is quite close to the same number of days as the orbital period of the planet Uranus. Hence my question - **Is there a formal name for this 84 year eclipse cycle?**

[Wikipedia Eclipse Cycle page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_cycle)

Comment: If it helps anyone - It is the same thing as a "triple Inex" minus a "hexon" = ~84 years

Comment: It is also the same as one "unidos" plus a "Metonic" cycle = 1039 lunations = ~84 years

Comment: You may enjoy https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4412720/207316

Comment: I assume it is probably an unnamed cycle then - BTW there are a number of errors in the updated Wikipedia table - for those who perhaps help to edit such things...